# Swift UITableView (with out scrolling) in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, uiscrollview

I am developing an app for website. I want to show post data. Each post has text and images. I wan to make one big scroll view to show this post content. I create UIViewController, where I insert UIScrollView.

In the UIScrollView I insert UILayer (which I make resizable) and UITableView (to show images). I want to make UITableView not scrollable but resizable. Can you help me?

Comment: Certainly you want scrolling, right? Otherwise you wouldn't be using a scrollview? In that case, why not ditch the scrollview and just use tableview?

Comment: Right! But, I want to scroll UIScrollView (where I will have text and images). If I have only images I will use only UITableView

Comment: I want to make sure I understand what you want to do. When you have text and images, you want to use the scrollview, but when you only have images, you want to use the tableview? You know you can have different kinds of prototype cells in one tableview, right? You can have a "TextOnlyCell", "ImageOnlyCell", and "TextAndImageCell". Then depending on the data in the post you can dequeue the appropriate cell, and it will all be one tableview.

Comment: Hm... You think I can use UITableView where I can define 2 prototypes of cells: text cell and image cell. It can work) I will try! Thank you!

Comment: Can a post have more than one image?

Comment: Is it possible to make text cell width resizable?

Comment: Do you want the text to scroll separately from the images?

Comment: No. First text, than images. All screen move together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol, ok I see where you're going with this. So what you will need to do is have an outer tableview. This is going to be the one that scrolls and contains the data of multiple posts. Then you only need one prototype cell. That prototype cell should have a UITextView and *another* tableview underneath for the images associate with that post. This tableview in the cell should not scroll, but should be resizable; I understand. In interface builder you can deselect the scrollable checkboxes, and use constraints to make it resizable.

Now here's the trick, the datasource for your images tableview needs to be the cell that contains it. The datasource for your outertableview will be its controller.

Does that make sense?

Comment: E.g. 1 cell will have text, 5 - images

Comment: You can do that if you wish but I wouldn't recommend it. What will happen is that you will have all the text of one post in its own TextCell prototype, followed by each picture for that post in its own ImageCell. The text and images won't be visually grouped together. It would be like me responding to this question with a text post, and then an image post, and another image post, and another image post, instead of having text and images all in the same post.

Comment: It's actually much easier code-wise (not to mention better practice) to have your PostCell prototype manage its own text view and images than to have your outer table view controller trying to manage everything.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to message me if you have more questions about how to implement this.

Comment: How can I make cell resizable? Only   `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
}`

Comment: I decided to make 1 table with 2 prototypes. I use UILabel for displaying text. I have to calculate UILabel height?

Comment: Yes you would have to use that method. You'll need to calculate the label height plus the height of the images.

Comment: Hello) I like your idea) Works perfect.
But, I need more help.

Comment: I this view i have toolbar, where I can scale font (it is not problem, I have done this). But I want to scale layers to. 
`label.frame.size.height = 100; label.setNeedsLayout()` does not works
How can I resize frames?

Comment: At some point you'll need to call `label.sizeToFit()` But if you are using constraints on the label you need to update the constraints and then call `layoutIfNeeded()` on the label's superview. It's not uncommon for me to have to make IBOutlets to connect to a layout constraint that I know I'll need to change. Are you using autolayout?

Comment: Yes. I use storyboard, where I set all sizes (and autosizes)

Comment: What are the constraints on your label?

Comment: Look at the photos: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0gau0ijb4iu21qe/AADMchFFv8CwWfgxrzu8yzJza?dl=0

Comment: So you'll need to make an IBOutlet to the constraint where you set the height to 52. Maybe call it `labelHeightConstraint` then in your code set `labelheightConstraint.constant = 100`.You may also have to call `setNeedsLayout()` on the label then.

Comment: Ok) I will try) Thank you!!! (P.S. my next question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29496821/extract-links-from-string-optimization-swift) ))))