# Extract links from string optimization

Tags: ios, string, swift

I get data (HTML string) from website. I want to extract all links. I write function (it works), but it is so slow...

Can you help me to optimize it? What standard functions I can use? 
Function logic: find "http:.//" sting in text, and then read string (buy char) until I will not get "\"".

```
extension String {

subscript (i: Int) -> Character {
    return self[advance(self.startIndex, i)]
}

subscript (i: Int) -> String {
    return String(self[i] as Character)
}

subscript (r: Range<Int>) -> String {
    return substringWithRange(Range(start: advance(startIndex, r.startIndex), end: advance(startIndex, r.endIndex)))
}}



func extractAllLinks(text:String) -> Array<String>{
var stringArray = Array<String>()
var find = "http://" as String

for (var i = countElements(find); i<countElements(text); i++)
{
    var ch:Character = text[i - Int(countElements(find))]
    if (ch == find[0])
    {
        var j = 0
        while (ch == find[j])
        {
            var ch2:Character = find[j]
            if(countElements(find)-1 == j)
            {
                break
            }
            j++
            i++
            ch = text[i - Int(countElements(find))]
        }

        i -= j
        if (j == (countElements(find)-1))
        {
            var str = ""
            for (; text[i - Int(countElements(find))] != "\""; i++)
            {
                str += text[i - Int(countElements(find))]
            }
            stringArray.append(str)
        }

    }
}
return stringArray}
```

Comment: You can use regular expression instead.

Comment: You can try open source library html parsing. http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Details

- Swift 5.2, Xcode 11.4 (11E146)

### Solution

```
// MARK: DataDetector

class DataDetector {

    private class func _find(all type: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType,
                             in string: String, iterationClosure: (String) -> Bool) {
        guard let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: type.rawValue) else { return }
        let range = NSRange(string.startIndex ..< string.endIndex, in: string)
        let matches = detector.matches(in: string, options: [], range: range)
        loop: for match in matches {
            for i in 0 ..< match.numberOfRanges {
                let nsrange = match.range(at: i)
                let startIndex = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: nsrange.lowerBound)
                let endIndex = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: nsrange.upperBound)
                let range = startIndex..<endIndex
                guard iterationClosure(String(string[range])) else { break loop }
            }
        }
    }

    class func find(all type: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType, in string: String) -> [String] {
        var results = [String]()
        _find(all: type, in: string) {
            results.append($0)
            return true
        }
        return results
    }

    class func first(type: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType, in string: String) -> String? {
        var result: String?
        _find(all: type, in: string) {
            result = $0
            return false
        }
        return result
    }
}

// MARK: String extension

extension String {
    var detectedLinks: [String] { DataDetector.find(all: .link, in: self) }
    var detectedFirstLink: String? { DataDetector.first(type: .link, in: self) }
    var detectedURLs: [URL] { detectedLinks.compactMap { URL(string: $0) } }
    var detectedFirstURL: URL? {
        guard let urlString = detectedFirstLink else { return nil }
        return URL(string: urlString)
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
let text = """
Lorm Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. apple.com/ Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. http://gooogle.com. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. yahoo.com It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
"""

print(text.detectedLinks)
print(text.detectedFirstLink)
print(text.detectedURLs)
print(text.detectedFirstURL)
```

### Console output

```
["apple.com/", "http://gooogle.com", "yahoo.com"]
Optional("apple.com/")
[apple.com/, http://gooogle.com, yahoo.com]
Optional(apple.com/)
```

Comment: It works almost perfectly!.. I found a crash using this snippet having emojis.
I've fixed it with the following for-in clause:

`for match in matches {`
          `guard iterationClosure((string as NSString).substring(with: match.range)) else {
            break
          }`
        `}`

Answer (score 31):

Like AdamPro13 said above using `NSDataDetector` you can easily get all the URLs, see it the following code :

```
let text = "http://www.google.com. http://www.bla.com"
let types: NSTextCheckingType = .Link
var error : NSError?

let detector = NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue, error: &error)        
var matches = detector!.matchesInString(text, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, count(text)))

for match in matches {
   println(match.URL!)
}
```

It outputs :

```
http://www.google.com
http://www.bla.com
```

> **Updated to Swift 2.0**

```
let text = "http://www.google.com. http://www.bla.com"
let types: NSTextCheckingType = .Link

let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue)

guard let detect = detector else {
   return
}

let matches = detect.matchesInString(text, options: .ReportCompletion, range: NSMakeRange(0, text.characters.count))

for match in matches {
    print(match.URL!)
}
```

Remember to use the `guard` statement in the above case it must be inside a function or loop.

I hope this help.

Comment: sorry it could not handle text  not contains any links. 
i tried "hello swift" 
    guard let detect = detector else {
        return
    }

 doesn't work

Comment: i am getting  this error  
**Cannot invoke initializer for type 'NSDataDetector' with an argument list of type '(types: UInt64, error: inout NSError?)'**

Answer (score 25):

And that is the answer for **Swift 5.0**

```
let text = "http://www.google.com. http://www.bla.com"

func checkForUrls(text: String) -> [URL] {
    let types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType = .link

    do {
        let detector = try NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue)

        let matches = detector.matches(in: text, options: .reportCompletion, range: NSMakeRange(0, text.count))
    
        return matches.compactMap({$0.url})
    } catch let error {
        debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    return []
}

checkForUrls(text: text)
```

Answer (score 4):

Very helpful thread! Here's an example that worked in Swift 1.2, based on [Victor Sigler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2695387/victor-sigler)'s answer.

```
    // extract first link (if available) and open it!
    let text = "How technology is changing our relationships to each other: http://t.ted.com/mzRtRfX"
    let types: NSTextCheckingType = .Link

    do {
        let detector = try NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue)
        let matches = detector.matchesInString(text, options: .ReportCompletion, range: NSMakeRange(0, text.characters.count))
        if matches.count > 0 {
            let url = matches[0].URL!
            print("Opening URL: \(url)")
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
        }

    } catch {
        // none found or some other issue
        print ("error in findAndOpenURL detector")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a class called `NSDataDetector` that will detect the link for you.

You can find an example of it on NSHipster here: http://nshipster.com/nsdatadetector/

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5.8.1**

```
import Foundation

extension String {
    var urls: [String] {
        var urlsArr = [String]()
        do {
            let detector = try NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
            detector.enumerateMatches(in: self, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, self.utf16.count), using: { (result, _, _) in
                if let nsrange = result?.range {
                    urlsArr.append((self as NSString).substring(with:nsrange))
                }
            })
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        return urlsArr
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let str = " Hello world. https://www.google.com , blabla ❤️ apple.com, www.test.com"
print(str.urls) //["https://www.google.com", "apple.com", "www.test.com"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you realise that every single time that you call countElements, a major complex function is called that has to scan all the Unicode characters in your string, and extract extended grapheme clusters from them and count them. If you don't know what an extended grapheme cluster is then you should be able to imagine that this isn't cheap and major overkill.

Just convert it to an NSString*, call rangeOfString and be done with it.

Obviously what you do is totally unsafe, because http:// doesn't mean there is a link. You can't just look for strings in html and hope it works; it doesn't. And then there is https, Http, hTtp, htTp, httP and so on and so on and so on. But that's all easy, for the real horror follow the link in Uttam Sinha's comment.

Comment: Thank you! I use constants `var textLength = countElements(text)
    var findLength = countElements(find)` (so I use countElements only 2 times) . Result - 2x faster. But NSDataDetector - space speed... I thin I will use it.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you are better off using regexes, data detectors or a parsing library.  However, as specific feedback on your string processing:

The key with Swift strings is to embrace the forward-only nature of them.  More often than not, integer indexing and random access is not necessary.  As @gnasher729 pointed out, every time you call `count` you are iterating over the string.  Similarly, the integer indexing extensions are linear, so if you use them in a loop, you can easily accidentally create a quadratic or cubic-complexity algorithm.

But in this case, there's no need to do all that work to convert string indices to random-access integers.  Here is a version that I think is performing similar logic (look for a prefix, then look from there for a " character - ignoring that this doesn't cater for https, upper/lower case etc) using only native string indices:

```
func extractAllLinks(text: String) -> [String] {
    var links: [String] = []
    let prefix = "http://"
    let prefixLen = count(prefix)

    for var idx = text.startIndex; idx != text.endIndex; ++idx {
        let candidate = text[idx..<text.endIndex]
        if candidate.hasPrefix(prefix),
           let closingQuote = find(candidate, "\"") {
            let link = candidate[candidate.startIndex..<closingQuote]
            links.append(link)
            idx = advance(idx, count(link))
        }
    }
    return links
}

let text = "This contains the link \"http://www.whatever.com/\" and"
         + " the link \"http://google.com\""

extractAllLinks(text)
```

Even this could be further optimized (the `advance(idx, count())` is a little inefficient) if there were other helpers such as `findFromIndex` etc. or a willingness to do without string slices and hand-roll the search for the end character.

Comment: Thank you! I understand the Idea, but I do not understand code  `let candidate = text[idx..<text.endIndex]
        if candidate.hasPrefix(prefix),
        let closingQuote = find(candidate, "\"") {
            let link = candidate[candidate.startIndex..<closingQuote]
            links.append(link)
            idx = advance(idx, count(link))
        }`
Can you describe it? (and fix, I can't compile it)

Comment: `let candidate = text[idx..<text.endIndex]` creates a substring starting at `idx`. Note, substrings are really just views into the real string, they don't create a new string. Then `if candidate.hasPrefix(prefix), let closingQuote = find(candidate, "\"") ` is saying, if that substring starts with "http", try to find the index of a closing quote within it.  If found, then it creates a new substring from the start up to that closing quote, and appends it to the array.  Finally, it moves `idx` forward by the length of the url just found.